# Can I get geoserver to recognize 'rectangle' in SLD?

Tags: geoserver, sld

Since geoexplorer is giving us problems, we have started using QGIS to style our layers and then put the sld in geoserver. The wellknownname for a square comes out as 'rectangle' from QGIS and geoserver doesn't recognize that. There is a team that has to do styles this way and would prefer to find a way around replacing rectangle with square every time they do a style. Can I get geoserver to recognize 'rectangle'?

Answer (score 3):

This issue was worked on during the OSGeo code sprint in Bonn. There is a pull request, that should be acted on soon: https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/1288/files
It adds rectangle to the known shapes.

Comment: I've merged the PR - it should appear in the latest jars later today

Comment: This is great. But how do I add it to my current geoserver?

Comment: You'll have to get the latest version of Geoserver

Comment: We'll eventually try to backport to GeoServer 2.9.x as well. It's too late for 2.8.x though, that series is not likely to see any more releases.